# Python selenium cannot find element even with wait

Tags: python, html, selenium

**I am trying to send text to an input field, but selenium is not able to find the element.**

```
element = WebDriverWait(b, 10).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, '/html/body/table/tbody/tr[1]/td/form/div/table/tbody/tr[2]/td/table[2]/tbody/tr/td[4]/table/tbody/tr/td[1]/input')))
element.send_keys("Customer Care", Keys.ENTER)
```

I've tried using the XPATH, the full XPATH and the ID to locate it, but it keeps giving me an error that indicates that it cannot find the element
`selenium.common.exceptions.TimeoutException`

A snippet of the HTML element

```html
<input class="iceInpTxt testBox" id="headerForm:jumpto" maxlength="40" name="headerForm:jumpto" onblur="setFocus('');iceSubmitPartial(form, this, event);" onfocus="setFocus(this.id);" onkeyup="iceSubmit(form,this,event);" onmousedown="this.focus();" type="text" value="">
```

Comment: Share HTML in text format or provide the URL

Comment: I know its not a solution but you can use https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/selenium-ide/mooikfkahbdckldjjndioackbalphokd?hl=en to capture test steps and probably even see why its timing out

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Element has `ID`, use it as locator. Check if element is inside a iframe:

```
wait = WebDriverWait(b, 10)
element = wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.ID, 'headerForm:jumpto')))
element.send_keys("Customer Care", Keys.ENTER)
```

How to switch to iframe:

```
wait = WebDriverWait(b, 10)

wait.until(EC.frame_to_be_available_and_switch_to_it((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "iframe_locator")))

element = wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.ID, 'headerForm:jumpto')))
element.send_keys("Customer Care", Keys.ENTER)

# How to go back to default content
b.switch_to.default_content()
```

Comment: It is in an iframe. What can I do about it?

Comment: Using code in the answer **how to switch to iframe**. Share html of the iframe

Answer (score 0):

If your usecase involves invoking `click()` or `send_keys()` while inducing [WebDriverWait](https://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/py/webdriver_support/selenium.webdriver.support.wait.html#module-selenium.webdriver.support.wait) instead of `presence_of_element_located()` you need to use the [expected_conditions](https://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/py/webdriver_support/selenium.webdriver.support.expected_conditions.html#module-selenium.webdriver.support.expected_conditions) as [`element_to_be_clickable()`](https://selenium.dev/selenium/docs/api/py/webdriver_support/selenium.webdriver.support.expected_conditions.html#selenium.webdriver.support.expected_conditions.element_to_be_clickable) as follows:

So effectively, you can use either of the following  [Locator Strategies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48369043/official-locator-strategies-for-the-webdriver/48376890#48376890):

- Using `CSS_SELECTOR`:

  ```
  WebDriverWait(b, 10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "input.iceInpTxt.testBox[id^='headerForm'][name$='jumpto']"))).send_keys("Customer Care", Keys.ENTER)
  ```
- Using `XPATH`:

  ```
  WebDriverWait(b, 10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//input[@class='iceInpTxt testBox' and @id='headerForm:jumpto'][@name='headerForm:jumpto']"))).send_keys("Customer Care", Keys.ENTER)
  ```

---

### References

You can find a couple of detailed discussion about the different expected_conditions in:

- [WebDriverWait not working as expected](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49775502/webdriverwait-not-working-as-expected/49775808#49775808)

Comment: @SisqoBaker Checkout the updated answer and let me know the status.

Answer (score 0):

it is a good idea to check whether or not you installed and imported selenium or other necessary packages. Use `pip` to check your version and see if there is a bug online. Please let me know what python version you are using. It is likely the `XPATH` you provided was incorrect or maybe try increasing the amount of time in the 2nd parameter of `WebDriverWait(1st,2nd)`. It would be much more helpful if you had a link to this html page so I could check your `XPATH`. If you'd like further help, please provide your html page.

Edit: 
This is something that needs to be reproduced so that it can be checked. If you have tried the above, I am unable to help unless I see the html document. You should remove all sensitive information before sharing it. The other elements of your code seem to be correct.

Comment: I am using python version Python 3.7.6. I am not able to provide the HTML page because that would involve me giving you my login credentials.

Comment: @SisqoBaker, At this point I recommend that you test each element in your `XPATH`.  Use `EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, thePath)` , first test that the `html` is there(to check if it's in the right format, I don't know how you accessed your html). Then you do ```body/table``` etc until you get to the one where it stops working.

Comment: @SisqoBaker I don't see any harm in providing the HTML and in the coarse of providing the text based relevant HTML you don't need to provide your credentials anyway. Rather without the HTML, neither you would get any canonical answer nor the contributors can test the locators they want to suggest you. So providing the HTML is a win-win situation for both.